# If I set wrapper to float left, absolute positioned inside elements disappear with 0 width and height

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I'm trying to create a slider that will be on the left of the container and there is other stuff that I'll add later to the right. For my slider I added an ul list and positioned items of it to absolute because, I'm trying to create a fadeIn/fadeOut kinda slider. So my problem is when I set container of ul which is #slider, items inside it diseapears and it sets everything including container to 0 width and height. What I don't understand is which block of my code cause this problem.

Here is my CSS/HTML:

```css
.clear {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.container {
  max-width: 900px;
}

#intro {
  padding: 0 15px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto 30px auto;
}

#slider {
  float: left;
  max-width: 630px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#slider::after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

#slider-images {
  background-color: #ccff00;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#slider-images::after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

#slider-images li {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#slider-images li img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

#slider-images li:hover::after {
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 25px -5px rgba(127, 130, 133, 0.25);
}

#slider-images li::after {
  transition: box-shadow .5s;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 15px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 95.19230769230769%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 1px rgba(127, 130, 133, 0.15);
}

#social {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<section id="intro" class="container border-box">
  <div id="slider">
    <ul id="slider-images">
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/slider/image-1.png"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/slider/image-2.png"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/slider/image-3.png"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/slider/image-4.png"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/slider/image-5.png"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="social">
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
</section>
```

and jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/6fsh1ctz/

Comment: setting #slider to display:block causes same problem. I think its somehow related to making #slider block

Comment: you need at least one child not in absolute position to give a size to the container . `#slider-images li +li` https://jsfiddle.net/jLg6ze40/